# how to keep track of an item in a binary file

Tags: c, file

i have two structs like this:

```
typedef struct user{
    char nick[NICKSIZE];
    char name[NAMESIZE];
    int n_messages;
    int n_following;
    int n_followers;
    following *arr_following;
    following *arr_unfollowed;
}user;

typedef struct user_pos {
    char nick[6];
    int position_in_file;
}user_pos;
```

I want to create an user and insert it into a binary file, but i also want to keep track of where the new user is storing its position in the `user_pos` struct, so i can later get him with fseek()

```
void insert_user(char *input_a, char *input_b){
    user *new_user = malloc(sizeof(user));
    strcpy(new_user->name, input_b);
    strcpy(new_user->nick, input_a);
    new_user->n_following = 0;
    new_user->n_messages = 0;
    new_user->n_followers = 0;
    new_user->arr_following = malloc(sizeof(following));
    new_user->arr_unfollowed = malloc(sizeof(following)); 

    FILE *fp = fopen("data_base.bin", "ab+");
    fwrite(&new_user, sizeof(new_user),1,fp);

    user_pos *new_user_pos = malloc(sizeof(user_pos));
    strcpy(new_user_pos->nick, input_a);
    new_user_pos->position_in_file = ????

    (...)
}
```

What exactly should i put here: `new_user_pos->position_in_file = ????` and then how would the fseek() function look like to retrieve the item?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OT: Storing a struct containing pointers is a dangerous path... Remember that the pointers are invalid on read back.

Comment: @4386427 how would you sugest i keep track of where that struct will be in a file? i read that a binary file can almost work as an array of structs and that is what i am trying to emulate

Comment: @4386427 well considering the answer of John Zwinck if i store the position where the struct is in the file, will that not emulate an array index? and the fseek() be similiar to find(array[x]) ?

Comment: @4386427 just to be clear, what you are suggesting is to instead store the value of sizeof(new_user) as the position where the struct is and later use the same value to retrieve the information?

Comment: No, I would store 0 for the first user in the file, 1 for the second user and so on. Just the same way as an array index works.

Comment: Writing raw structures into a file is an excellent way to have your files become unreadable suddenly because you upgraded your compiler. Don't do that. Serialize the data properly.

Comment: @4386427 oh ok, that is indeed a good approach that i didnt think off, thanks, i will consider using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ftell()` before `fwrite()` to get the position in the file (i.e. the byte where the write began).

You can use `fseek(fp, position_in_file, SEEK_SET)` to jump to that position later.

Be sure to handle the return codes of every function--a write could fail for example if the disk is full.

Comment: will the return of the function ftell() be an int?

Comment: @MiguelD: I'm sure you can answer that question for yourself within two seconds.

Comment: ok just another question, if i remove an item from the file, will the location of the other items be affected resulting in the positions i have stored being useless?

Comment: @MiguelD: There is no way to "remove an item from the file" unless it is at the very end (in which case you can use `ftruncate()`, and no other items will be affected).

Comment: @JohnZwinck but i still can change the content of the struct stored in the file, right? thats why i want to keep track of the the struct is, for later being its contents get updated if needed

Comment: @MiguelD: Yes of course you can overwrite it by `fseek()` then `fwrite()` again.